# Shopify gem: Is there a way to retrieve all shipping methods for a shop?

Tags: ruby, shopify

I thought it would be on the `ShopifyAPI::Shop` object, but it doesn't look like that's where I find the shipping methods configured for a shop. Is there a way to do this using the current API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently possible to fetch shipping methods using the API.